# AngularJS unexpected request ngmock

Tags: javascript, angularjs, httpbackend, angularjs-ngmock

I get an unexpected request error on `GET /#/car/view/0` where 0 is the `:carId`.

It's for a basic angular crud application on a ngMock backend. The `$httpBackend.whenGET(carUrl)` works and gives back a list of all cars. The `addCar()` also works.

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong with getting the detailed view

I need some help with getting the correct url's and to get a detailed view by id. Obviously the code below works because the url's are static but I can't find the right way to get the url with the ID variable.

thecode:

**App.js**

routing:

```
.when('/car', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/car/car.html'

    })
    .when('/car/view/:carId', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/car/carView.html',
        controller: 'carViewCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'ctrl'
    })
    .when('/car/addCar', {
        templateUrl: 'pages/car/carAdd.html'
    })
```

app.run:
*this is where my mock backend is defined*

```
window.app.run(function($httpBackend) {
var cars = [
  {
    id: 0, 
    name: ‘car0’, 
    address: 'adress0', 
    tel: 'tel0', 
    email: 'email0'}, 
  {
    id: 1, 
    name: ‘car1’, 
    address: 'adress1', 
    tel: 'tel1', 
    email: 'email1'
  }];

var carUrl = “/#/car”;

//this works and gives back the list of all cars
$httpBackend.whenGET(carUrl).respond(function(method,url,data) {
     return [200, cars, {}];
});

//this is where it goes wrong I think
$httpBackend.whenGET(‘/#/car/view/:carId').respond(function(method, url, data){
     return [200, cars, {} ];
});

});
```

**CarService.js**

```
window.app.service(‘CarService', ['HTTPService', '$q', '$http', function (HTTPService, $q, $http) {
'use strict';

cars = [];
this.showDetails = function (carId){
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    HTTPService.get('/car/view/' + carId).then(function resolve(response){

    deferred.resolve(response.data);

    }, function reject(response){
        deferred.reject(response);
    });

    return deferred.promise;
};
```

**carView.js**

```
window.app.controller(‘carViewCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$location', ‘CarService', function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, CarService) {
'use strict';

$scope.carId = $routeParams.carId;
initCar($scope.carId);

function initCar(carId) {
    CarService.showDetails(carId).then(function success(car) {
    $scope.car = car;
    }, function error(response) {

    });
   }
 }]);
```

**carList.html**

```
<tr ng-repeat=“car in cars track by $index">
        <td>{{$index}}</td>
        <td><a href=“/#/car/view/{{car.id}}”>{{car.id}}</a></td>
        <td>{{car.name}}</td>
        <td>edit</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The url for `$httpBackend.whenGET` is either a `string`, `regex` or a function the returns true or false.

So you are only providing a string which won't match, you need to supply a regex that matches such as `/\/#\/car\/view\/(.+)/`

To access the data you capture with the regex you need to specify params that line up with your capture groups

```
$httpBackend.whenGET(/\/#\/car\/view\/(.+)/, undefined, undefined, 
    ['carID'])
.respond(function(method, url, data, headers, params) {
     return [200, {myReponse: 'this worked'}
});
```

To go into more details, from the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend#query-parameters):

> Regex parameter matching
>   If an expectation or definition uses a regex to match the URL, you can provide an array of keys via a params argument. The index of each key in the array will match the index of a group in the regex.
>
> The params object in the callback will now have properties with these keys, which hold the value of the corresponding group in the regex.
>
> This also applies to the when and expect shortcut methods.

What this means is that for the `expect` or `when` (such as `whenGET`) methods you can use a regular expression to match a url. Then for each capture group, which are whats inside of a `( )` block, you can store it in a variable which will be passed to your callback in the params object.

So, for a working example take a look at [this plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/nf9yWtYRlD1fxCOQMPTi?p=preview). As a side note, it seems that older versions of angular-mocks don't support this functionality as I got an error that `carId` was not defined for angular v1.2.23

Comment: Thanks for replying. I just tried it and it now gives me `carId not defined`. 
I don't fully understand how I can access the data, can you explain a little bit more?? Thanks!

Comment: @Joey Ciecahnowisz could you please explain it a little more. I am also stuck with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks! I got it to work. I didn't use the plunker, it caused some errors when I tried to implement that but by following the docs you linked I solved my problem.